# Regular expression to validate a Google Analytics UA Number

Tags: regex, google-analytics

It's not 100 percent clear to me that the Google Analytics UA Numbers are always 6 digits, a dash, and 2 digits as Google often mentions in their documentation. There are frequent counter-examples that use fewer than 6 for the account portion and 1-4 for the profile. All of the examples always show numbers but it's not even clear that they can't be letters.

Does anyone know if Google has published a regex that exactly matches allowable UA Numbers? I'm adding this feature to the admin console of an application I work on and would like to validate the user input.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Perhaps there is no fixed range of digits.  6 digits for the account number would limit Google to 1,000,000 users.  I'm sure Google aims higher than that.  This [Google Analytics FAQ item](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81977) shows `UA-xxxxxxx-y` as a sample account number (7 + 1 digits).  I would presume that only the UA and dashes are fixed and that the number of digits expands as the number of users and profiles grows.  E.g. to allow 4 to 10 digits for the user and 1 to 4 digits for the profile you could use this Perl-style regex:

```
\bUA-\d{4,10}-\d{1,4}\b
```

If it has to work with the limited [Google Analytics regex syntax](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55582) try this:

```
UA-[0-9]+-[0-9]+
```

Comment: Yeah, I said it was 6 because I didn't do a count, just a quick glance. :p I was leaning towards the second regex also but wasn't sure if they did allow letters.

Comment: Carlo in this thread http://carlorizzante.com/2011/sanitize-the-google-analytics-tracking-code/ states that UA-1234567 is still a valid ID.  I'd rather be conservative and try not to reject a possibly valid code, so I think I'm going to use: \bUA-\d{4,10}(-\d{1,4})?\b

Comment: Nice, `/\bUA-\d{4,10}-\d{1,4}\b/` works admirably for :format in Ruby validators. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of mid-2021 there are now additional formats, and there may be further formats in the future. There is a pattern which will work for almost all active formats and will likely be honoured for future formats.

```regex
/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]?-[A-Z0-9]{4,10}(?:\-[1-9]\d{0,3})?$/
```

( stackoverflow regex syntax highlighter doesn't seem to like ^ )

Existing codes include:
UA YT MO G DC AW

UA-12345-1
G-J2DV45G
DC-JGWWE32
AW-GER322

If you're trying to match a code in a longer string try using the word boundary `\b` option...

```regex
/\b[A-Z][A-Z0-9]?-[A-Z0-9]{4,10}(?:\-[1-9]\d{0,3})?\b/
```

Explaination (without ^|$|\b additions):

- Match a single character present in the list below [A-Z]
- A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
- Match a single character present in the list below [A-Z0-9]
- ? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
- 0-9 matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- - matches the character - with index 4510 (2D16 or 558) literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character present in the list below [A-Z0-9]
  {4,10} matches the previous token between 4 and 10 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
- 0-9 matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- Non-capturing group (?:-[1-9]\d{0,3})?
- ? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- \- matches the character - with index 4510 (2D16 or 558) literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character present in the list below [1-9]
  1-9 matches a single character in the range between 1 (index 49) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
  {0,3} matches the previous token between 0 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)