# How to validate Google Analytics tracking id using a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, regex, google-analytics

I need to validate a Google Analytics tracking ID. So I created a simple function but my RegEx must be wrong because it just returns false everytime. I'm not sure if there is a set amount of digits in the middle or at that end of a Google Analytics ID so was just trying to just look for at least one digit.

JavaScript Function:

```
function validateGA(id) {
    var regexp = /ua-\d+-\w\d+/;
    return regexp.test(id);
}
```

Tested with `validateGA('UA-12345-12');` but just keep returning false.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9yLr/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GA ID does not have a fixed number of digits in it. Also, There have been legacy ids that started with `MO` or `YT` etc. For your purposes, the correct regex could be something like:

```
/(UA|YT|MO)-\d+-\d+/i.test(id)
```

This works for following scenarios:

```
UA-1234-12
YT-1234-12
MO-1-1
UA-1234-1
ua-1-1
UA-1234- // Invalid
UA--1   // Invalid
```

Also, To check this in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4mkH/1/

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to also mention that the newest version of Google Analytics allows letters in the second part of the Tracking ID - for instance, this is now valid:

G-2RJ8P0I4GC

This is the regex I ended up using:

^(G|UA|YT|MO)-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$

Answer (score 5):

[@Avi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412153/762279) answer is pretty close, but it will fail in the following cases:

```
test-UA-1234-12
UA-1234-12-test
```

So, the Javascript function with the correct regex is:

```
function validateGAId(id) {
  return /^(UA|YT|MO)-\d+-\d+$/i.test(id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know JS but it needs to be case insensitive to match the `UA`

either `/(?i)ua-\d+-\w\d+/` or `/ua-\d+-\w\d+/i`

Answer (score 0):

There are now additional formats, and there may be further formats in the future.

You may want to review this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/68679610/897266